# How would you capture the RTP stream during a Google Hangout conversation using WireShark?

Tags: network-protocols, wireshark

So I was trying to capture RTP stream and calculate jitter. I know google hangouts uses multiple protocols. So the way I did it was by first filtering the UDP packets then decoded as RTP. When I do RTP stream analysis it shows jitter as 0. Is there some other way to do this?

My goal is to capture just the RTP packets and calculate jitter during a google + hangout session.